# Strange: property "set" in ASP.NET markup not actually being set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

So I find this truly bizarre and I'm wondering if anyone has heard of something like this or could fathom what might be going on...

I have a user control foo.ascx. In foo.ascx I declare 3 public properties: val1 val2 and val3. Each is declared identically: public int.

In a page I use my foo control and in the tag I set val1="10" val2="11" val3="12". Note that I am doing this in Visual Studio and intellisense verifies that my properties exist as expected.

I put a break point in the Page_Load method and inspect the property values: val1 is 10, val2 is 0 and val3 is 12. WTF?

So originally my properties were just { get; set; } type properties, but for debugging purposes I put some code into the get and set methods for each. I put a breakpoint in each setter where I can inspect "value". The setter for each property has its breakpoint hit EXCEPT for val2 where nothing happens.

I've also got an Application_Error handler in global.asax.cs with an active breakpoint and no error is detected.

Has anyone heard of a property being skipped like this, or does anyone know how I might better trace the execution of the request in order to figure out what's really going on?

Edit: I am using .NET 3.5 and running on the local dev server in Visual Studio 2008

Edit #2: I can't post the code because it's my company's not mine but I can say:

1. The control inherits only from System.Web.UI.UserControl
2. I have a breakpoint at the beginning of every single method in the class and NO code within the class is executed other than the setters and Page_Load.

Edit #3:

OK so this is very interesting. I started thinking that somehow there was a naming conflict that was not being caught by the compiler (no compiler warnings related to this issue BTW) but couldn't fathom where the name could be coming from. Now I see that the name *sort of* exists within the same scope. The actual name of the property is "ClientId" and that is very close to "ClientID" which it turns out is a member of System.Web.UI.Control which I inherit from via UserControl. Now technically C# is case sensitive so its not a naming collision... but what about the markup? Is that case sensitive? I don't know and my google searches seem to bring up "yes" and "no" both.

So anyway I tested this by inspecting the ClientID property of my control and it was still set to the auto-generated one. But that's because this property is readonly... is it possible that I'm inadvertently trying to assign to a different property because I'm in a case-insensitive environment? Like I said I cannot verify because ClientID is readonly but this seems *very* sensible to me.

Comment: Might be related to the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations)

Comment: I would guess you've got a logic error somewhere. Perhaps show us some code so we can take a look.

Comment: @Jagd please see edit #2... I'd post code if I could however given that no code in the class is executing besides Page_Load and the setters I don't see anywhere for such a logic error to exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CDspace how specifically do you think this might relate to the page lifecycle?

Comment: @Paul you state you're using a user control. I've had issues with initialization and loading orders before when trying to setup a user control

Comment: @CDspace this is the kind of experience I was hoping someone may have had... can you elaborate on how you approached debugging such issues?

Comment: @Paul Using the link I provided, I went through and looked at when each event was fired. In my case I needed the user control to load some values before the page, so moved that code into the controls OnInit, which fires before the Page_Load

Comment: @CDspace I would find this relation to the lifecycle more compelling if I didn't have two seemingly identically scoped and typed properties next to the problematic one and everything works fine for them. As I said I have breakpoints in every method and one in the application's global error handler and nothing comes up.

Comment: I also realize this issue seems rather vaporous and I appreciate you taking the time to suggest things despite said vapourosity.. even though I am challenging the suggestions :)

Comment: @Paul without seeing the code, it's hard to help any further. Can you recreate a small example you can post?

Comment: @CDspace part of my issue here is that I can't recreate a small example that actually exhibits this behaviour because, well, the examples work! But you're right there isn't a heck of a lot that can be done without the code... I'm more just looking for debug/trace approaches that might be more successful than what I'm presently doing. So thank you very much for your suggestion but unless I am able to either gain new information or recreate the issue in an example I don't think there's much more you can do. I actually feel bad posting such a ghost-like problem for exactly this reason :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I see that the name sort of exists within the same scope. The actual name of the property is "ClientId" and that is very close to "ClientID" which it turns out is a member of System.Web.UI.Control which I inherit from via UserControl. Now technically C# is case sensitive so its not a naming collision... but what about the markup? Is that case sensitive? I don't know and my google searches seem to bring up "yes" and "no" both.

I believe the markup is case-insensitive (easy to check, so I'll leave it to you to do so).  And that it will therefore update the first matching property if you have more than one property that only differ in case.

What I would to is look at the source code generated from the markup.  An easy way to do this is:

- Add a server script block to your markup that contains a compilation error:

  ```
  <script runat="server">
    Some invalid C# syntax
  </script>
  ```
- Run under the debugger and navigate to the relevant page
- An error page will be displayed that includes a link to display the full generated source code.
- Examine the source code to see which property is being set.

Comment: The generated source appears correct: ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute("ClientId", "82"); HOWEVER I have no idea how this SetAttribute method works... I'll google for it.

Comment: I see the HtmlControl class has a case insensitive implementation of SetAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol(v=vs.100).ASPX) I guess it's possible UserControl is also case insensitive however the documentation on that piece makes no comment one way or the other (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383214(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also +1 for the instructions on seeing the generated source... that never occurred to me!

Comment: @Paul - "I guess it's possible UserControl is also case insensitive" - it is case-insensitive - IlSpy is your friend - which makes sense, as it needs to work with case-insensitive languages such as VB.NET.

Comment: I'd give you another +1 for this ILSpy thing... I've known for a while I need to learn about IL and other "bare metal" .NET topics but just haven't had the time yet. Thank you very much for confirming what I could not!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code, I can only guess. However, I suspect there is a typo somewhere. Perhaps you are setting val3 twice.

Anyway, these problems often end up being something logically obvious but difficult to see on the screen.

Comment: As I said, intellisense confirms the variable's existence and spelling. Furthermore I did copy/paste the property name from the C# code into the markup just to be sure. I'm quite sure it's spelled properly.

Comment: As for setting the value twice, I have a breakpoint in the setter and it is *never* hit and that is my issue (not, say, an anomalous value).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing too, but besides the obvious hard-to-find typo, could it be that you are using some kind of *reserved/special word* for the property that is not working? ("reserved" in broadest of senses)

What happens if you change `val2` to something like `whenSpelledLikeThisItWorks` in both the code and the page?

Comment: Well that's kind of what I'm thinking of now too... please see Edit #3. If I can find confirmation of the markup being case insensitive then this is likely the answer.